# How to access element by passing selector in jquery?

Tags: jquery, selector

I want to get content of `#chocolate_type` by passing `lqjmje5plsqnl258canal0lmb0!323`
as parameter to jQuery. I tried:

```
$('#'+id).find('td:first').html();
```

but it didn't work. Here's the markup:

```
<tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center" id="lqjmje5plsqnl258canal0lmb0!323">
    <td id="chocolate_type">Chocolate Hearts</td>
    <td>2.79</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector fails because of the exclamation mark. If you are using Firefox, check your console and you should see a error like this:

> Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: !323

Remove the exclamation mark from the ID if you can. The allowed characters for an ID can be found here:

> http://www.electrictoolbox.com/valid-characters-html-id-attribute/

Using `$('tr[id='+id+']')` will work also but you really shouldn't depend on that as the functionality may change due to this being undefined behaviour.

Comment: thnx a lot..:) '!' was the problem

Comment: Linking some page with unreferenced info on the matter (albeit it being paraphrased from the W3C spec, as it turns out) seems to be inferior compared to [Geoff Appleford's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4561044/1529709).

Answer (score 2):

Your id contains invalid characters. From the w3c:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

More info [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `lqjmje5plsqnl258canal0lmb0!323` doesn't seem to be a good value for the id. The id value should not start with a number and you should avoid using special characters as value for the id:

```
$('#lqjmje5plsqnl258canal0lmb0!323 #chocolate_type').html();
```

---

You can also directly get the contents by id:

```
$('#chocolate_type').html();
```

Comment: I removed '!' but wht problem would arise by starting id with numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks ok, but you can't use the `!` character in an ID. I think that may be your problem.

You may use `$('#' + id).find('td:first')`, `$('td:first', '#' + id)`, `$('#' + id + ' td:first')` or whatever you like. I believe there is a performance comparison for all this somewhere, I'll see if I can find it.

EDIT: here's a very interesting article about jQuery performance, which says `find()` is better than context: http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-advanced-jquery-performance-tuning-tips-from-paul-irish. So, you're doing it right. Just change the id :)

Comment: however '!' was d evil...thnx u guys

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this `$('tr[id=' + id + ']').html()`. This worked for me. This is just the sample. In your case it would become `$('tr[id=' + id + ']').find('td:first').html()`.

Update: `$('#' + id)` is the right way to find the element when your id is in some other variable. However in your case `!` is causing problem and preventing it to work.

Comment: I'm not sure if using `tr[id=' + id + ']` is optimized to become `$('#' + id)`, but it's certainly not better. `$('#' + id)` uses native `document.getElementById()`, which is pretty much the fastest way to look up an element in the DOM (see for example here: http://www.componenthouse.com/article-19).

Answer (score 0):

It is better to write code in such a way

```
$('tr#'+id+' td:first').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue building a search form, as I used the search context to build to rebuild the form after each submission. A search for "!#/ \", for example would generate some invalid IDs.

For many simple types of invalid characters (especially when you're auto-generating IDs and can't tightly control the input), fail over to JavaScript:

> document.getElementById(yourElementId);

will work just fine.